# Backpack for Laravel - Permissionmanager: Can't create new user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, permissions, laravel-backpack

I have the following problem. I am using Backpack for Laravel with the `PermissionManager Extension.` By default, you have to log in via your email address. However, you can change that to log in with a username. Works fine if I (for example) seed the database. But for some strange reason, I can not create new users via the PermissionManager `PermissionManager Extension`. If I try the following error message is the result:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a
>   default value 
>       (SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
>       values (2018-11-29 22:26:32, 2018-11-29 22:26:32))

Just for testing, I gave the `name` column a default value, but the error message is the same, except the error now is:

> `Field 'username' doesn't have a default value.`

It just takes the next column in my database.

Of course, I've changed the CRUD-Requests, Form-Requests and so on, to store a username instead of an email. But it looks like the Request doesn't get my form values. It only tries to store the timestamps.

Strange thing: If I reverse all I did in the Controllers and so on and create an email column again, it will just work fine... did I overlook something?
How can I solve this error and store users with a username instead of an email?

#### Edit:

[image]

This is even odder... The data gets posted.

**Edit 2:**
After taking a really close look at the error messages I found the following:
[image]
As you can see, the array with my filled in data is still here.
[image]
However, in the next instance, the `parameters` array is completely empty as well as the `$instance` array.

Comment: Change field "name" as null in table. It is set to not null I guess.

Comment: As I already said: The error message just switches to: `General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value`. Also, the name field is required for my site.

Comment: Have you fill $fillable array in a model? If not, try to add all table fields to $fillable.
Do you gave rules() in controller? Try to add 'sometimes' for all fields:

for example
`public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'sometimes',
            'username' => 'sometimes',
....
        ];
    }`

Comment: Yes, I added all fields to the $fillable array that should be fillable. Do you think I have to add the primary_key and all other fields, like timestamps, as well? Because normally you wouldn't. Is this for test purposes? I will try the "sometimes" solution later this day. What response is expected?

Comment: I've made an edit to my post. Your way did not work out.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: In order to using username you have to edit app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController and add a new method called username

```
public function username(){
    return 'username';
}
```

Step 2: In User model make sure you use AuthenticatesUsers trait and add username field in fillable array.
Step 3: Make sure in app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController you add the username validation and add username field in create method.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email'    => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

That's all. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: It seemed promising to me, unfortunately, I did this already. There is no problem with logging in or registering in my laravel app. Also, I can create users via (for example) `User::create();`. My only problem is, that I can't create a user via the `PermissionManager` extension of `BackpackforLaravel`. I customized the CRUD-Requests and Controllers... everything. And I got no clue why this is.

Answer (score 1):

When this issue happened for me, I think I caused it by running `php artisan vendor:publish` instead of following the instructions and running `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Backpack\PermissionManager\PermissionManagerServiceProvider` first.

My `config/laravel-permission.php` file didn't just have the permission and user models incorrect, but the entire file was spatie's version instead of Laravel Backpack's version. My guess is that spatie's `vendor:publish` register typically runs before Laravel Backpack PermissionManager's.

Comment: I could cry ... Unfortunately, it still has not solved the damn problem. When I looked into the configs, I had to realize that even your suggestion was already set automatically.

Comment: Yes there are. But sometimes you forget installing and do it manually. I updated my answer. I think it will be helpful for you!!

Comment: Alright, so what I tried was reinstalling the package and made sure to follow your instructions. I made sure that it is not spaties config. However, it still does not work. Btw, I don't have a config named `laravel-permission.php`, but I have one that's named `permission.php`. It is the same config though. We are probably using different versions.

Comment: yes it is. But it helped to me. Whatever we can see. What we can to do that to fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

Never used this package before but I reviewed this package's files from github for solving your problem,  i saw some thing in the `UserCrudController.php` file. The file provides default user CRUD operations. The create and update form items define via setup method in this controller. But i don't see any define for `username` field.

as I understand it, your user table has a `username` and in your model  `$fillable` variable contains `username` and the user create/update form does not post `username` field to controller.

Can you try define `username` form element in to `UserCrudController.php` file for `username`, or remove  `username` attribute from $fillable in your model.

I hope these solve your problem.

Comment: Of course, I changed the CRUD-Controller as well. But for debugging purposes, I never tried to just remove the column from $fillable and the CRUD-Controller. Will try that out.